# Rails Mysql2::Error: SHOW command denied to user

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails, ruby, activerecord

I hope you can help me, I'm having some troubles with ruby on rails 4.2.7, I'm trying to copy some information from external db to my rails app using an select() but keeps giving me this error:

Mysql2::Error: SHOW command denied to user 'ROUser'@'fixed-185-188-150-30.totalplay.net' for table 'areas': SHOW CREATE TABLE `program` (ActiveRecord::StatementInvalid)

Checking my rails log, displays that executes this sql:

```
SELECT idprogram, programname, status FROM `program`
```

And the same error above.

But if I connect manually to that same external database with same user and password with mysql workbench, and then run the same sql statement, it works fine, the table exists in the external db.

I'm using rails 4.2.7 and mysql2 0.3.18

If I execute show grants to that table in mysql workbench I get this:

'GRANT SELECT (idprogram, programname, status) ON `mydbname`.`program` TO 'ROUser'@'%'

Comment: The activerecord pattern tries to determine the structure of your table so it can determine that idprogram is an int, programname is a varchar, etc. To do that, it will execute a `SHOW CREATE TABLE` query. That's a separate permission you need to grant to your ROUser.